# TypeScript - How to merge interfaces that share same property?

Tags: typescript, interface

-- **Problem** --

I would like to extend the `IAction` interface but both `ISetContextAction` and `IClearContextAction` interfaces share a same property which is `type`.

```
interface ISetContextAction {
  type: 'SET_CONTEXT';
  payload: string;
}

interface IClearContextAction {
  type: 'CLEAR_CONTEXT';
}

interface IAction extends ISetContextAction, IClearContextAction {}
```

However, this results in an error saying :

```
Interface 'IAction' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ISetContextAction' and 'IClearContextAction'.
  Named property 'type' of types 'ISetContextAction' and 'IClearContextAction' are not identical.
```

-- **What I have done** --

(1) Setting `payload` to optional and create a single interface instead of extending it (but I am curious if there's another approach)

```
interface IAction {
  type: 'SET_CONTEXT' | 'CLEAR_CONTEXT';
  payload?: string;
}
```

(2) Change `interface` to `type`

I have seen a lot of tutorials using `type` instead of `interface` :

```
type Actiontype = 
  | { type: 'SET_CONTEXT', payload: string }
  | { type: 'CLEAR_CONTEXT' };
```

-- **Question** --

Is there a workaround to merge interfaces that share a same property? (In this case, `type`)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the conflicting property, though it makes sense to do it when you need to actually create a new interface based on existing one, with some changes/additions.

For example:

```
interface IAction extends Omit<ISetContextAction, 'type'>, Omit<IClearContextAction, 'type'> {
  type: 'SET_CONTEXT' | 'CLEAR_CONTEXT';
}
```

But in your case union type is probably the correct approach, otherwise the example above forces you to define `payload` regardless of the action type.

Comment: "in your case union type is probably the correct approach....". This might be true as [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) says "if you can’t express some shape with an interface and you need to use a union or tuple type, type aliases are usually the way to go."